# Bash variable execution

Tags: bash, shell-script

I try to learn bash as i can.
In this example, when i use my script without argument :

```
restart_alfresco.sh
Connection to slql-fresc-bdd1 closed.

Usage: /root/bin/restart_alfresco.sh  status|start|stop|restart
```

The problem is that :

```
POSTGRES_STATUS=$(ssh -t root@slql-fresc-bdd1 "ps -f -u alfresco|grep postgres|grep -v UID")
```

is executed.
How can i use my $POSTGRES_STATUS without being executed ?

Here's my script :

```
FLOWER_STATUS="/etc/init.d/flowerGenesisPlugin status"
SOLR_STATUS=$(ps -f -u alfresco|grep -v UID)
ALFRESCO_STATUS=$(ps -f -u alfresco|grep Dalfresco|grep -v UID)
POSTGRES_STATUS=$(ssh -t root@slql-fresc-bdd1 "ps -f -u alfresco|grep postgres|grep -v UID")

usage() {
  # On display usage and exit.
  echo -e "\nUsage: ${0} \033[33m status|start|stop|restart\033[0m\n " >&2
  echo -e '\033[36m [status] \033[0m Permet de voir le status de alfresco, solr et flowergenesis' >&2
  echo -e '\033[36m [restart] \033[0m  Permet de restarter alfresco, solr et flowergenesis' >&2
  echo -e '\033[36m [stop] \033[0m  Permet de stopper solr, alfresco et flowergenesis' >&2
  echo -e '\033[36m [start] \033[0m  Permet de starter alfresco, solr et flowergenesis' >&2
  echo -e "\n"
}

status() {
echo -e "\n"
echo -e "$POSTGRES_STATUS"

if
        [[ -n "${POSTGRES_STATUS}" ]]
        then
        echo -e '\033[36m Postgres est bien start \033[0m' >&2
        else
        echo -e '\033[36m Postgres est eteint \033[0m' >&2
fi

echo -e "\n"
echo -e "$ALFRESCO_STATUS"
${ALFRESCO_STATUS}

if
        [[ -n "${ALFRESCO_STATUS}" ]]
        then
        echo -e '\033[36m Alfresco est bien start \033[0m' >&2
        else
        echo -e '\033[36m Alfresco est bien stop \033[0m' >&2
fi

echo -e "\n"
echo -e "$SOLR_STATUS"|grep -i --color=auto solr &&
${SOLR_STATUS}

if
        [[ -n "${SOLR_STATUS}" ]]
        then
        echo -e '\033[36m Solr est bien start \033[0m' >&2
        else
        echo -e '\033[36m Solr est arrete \033[0m' >&2
fi

echo -e "\n"
${FLOWER_STATUS}
FLOWER_EXIT_STATUS="${?}"

if
        [[ "${FLOWER_EXIT_STATUS}" -eq 0 ]]
        then
        echo -e '\033[36m flowerGenesisPlugin est bien start \033[0m' >&2
        else
        echo -e '\033[36m flowerGenesisPlugin est eteint \033[0m' >&2
fi
}


start() {
echo -e '\033[36m Demarrage de la Base Postgres en cours veuillez patientez \033[0m'
ssh -t root@slql-fresc-bdd1 "service postgres start" &&
service alfresco start &&
service solr start &&
/etc/init.d/flowerGenesisPlugin start
}

stop() {
service solr stop &&
service alfresco stop &&
/etc/init.d/flowerGenesisPlugin stop &&
echo -e "\033[36m Arret de la Base Postgres en cours veuillez patientez \033[0m"
ssh -t root@slql-fresc-bdd1 "service postgres stop"
}

case "$1" in
    status) status ;;
    start)   start ;;
    stop)    stop ;;
    restart) stop; start ;;
    *) usage >&2 ;;
       esac

if [[ "${UID}" -ne 0 ]]
then
  echo 'il faut executer ce script en tant que root' >&2
  usage
fi

# Expect the best
EXIT_STATUS='0'

if [[ "${EXIT_STATUS}" -ne 0 ]]
    then
      EXIT_STATUS=${EXIT_STATUS}
      echo "Execution du script a echoue." >&2
fi
```

Comment: You definitely haven't provided us with your entire script because in your example the usage message is being displayed but that function is never called in the script that you have provided.  It's also unclear what you are asking

Comment: the problem is that when i run my script without argument i just want to read the usage() fonction. Actually the variable POSTGRES_STATUS is executed when i run the script without argument.

It's true when i use on terminal :
[root@slql-fresc-web1 ~]# POSTGRES_STATUS=$(ssh -t root@slql-fresc-bdd1 "ps -f -u alfresco|grep postgres|grep -v UID")
Connection to slql-fresc-bdd1 closed.

So i would to have this variable definition without having the ssh command being executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the problem is that when i run my script without argument i just want to read the usage() fonction.

Well, consider the structure of your script, and the fact that the shell executes it starting from the top:

```
FLOWER_STATUS="/etc/init.d/flowerGenesisPlugin status"
SOLR_STATUS=$(ps -f -u alfresco|grep -v UID)
ALFRESCO_STATUS=$(ps -f -u alfresco|grep Dalfresco|grep -v UID)
POSTGRES_STATUS=$(ssh -t root@slql-fresc-bdd1 "ps -f -u alfresco|grep postgres|grep -v UID")

usage() {
   ...
}

case "$1" in
    status) status ;;
    start)   start ;;
    stop)    stop ;;
    restart) stop; start ;;
    *) usage >&2 ;;
esac
```

The very first thing you have in the script are the assignments to `POSTGRES_STATUS` and friends. They contain command substitutions, which run *at the time of assignment*. There's no lazy evaluation in the shell as there is in make. <sub>(Other than what you rig up with `eval`, but let's not go there.)</sub>

To avoid that, either move the argument check to the top, and the assignments under that:

```
usage() {
   echo...
}

case "$1" in 
   ...
   *) usage; exit 1 ;;
esac

POSTGRES_STATUS=...
```

Or, put the assignments in a function too, and only call that after the check.

```
usage() {
    echo...
}
check() {
    case "$1" in...
        *) usage; exit 1;;
    esac
}
set_globals() {
    POSTGRES_STATUS=...
}

check
set_globals
```

You could also put the main part of the code in a dedicated function (`main()`, usually) and call that from the very end, so that there would be no code on the main level apart from function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help ilkkachu, i will try to more use fonction to get a cleaner code.

I finally went for putting my variable inside the fonction status :

```
status() {
local POSTGRES_STATUS=$(ssh -t root@myhost "ps -f -u process|grep postgres|grep -v UID")
echo -e "\n"
echo -e "$POSTGRES_STATUS"
```